# Requesting a ruby-on-rails application gives Psych::BadAlias error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I ran the rails server from my application directory.
But when I tried to do a request from the browser with

```
http://localhost:3000
```

I get the following error:

*Psych::BadAlias

Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`: Unknown alias: default*

Answer (score 3):

This happens because the ruby-plugin for netbeans messes the database.yml file when creating project from existing source. It replaces the comment about sqlite3 to mysql, but even worse it erases the first definition block which is 'default'

So simply insert

```
default: &default
adapter: sqlite3
pool: 5
timeout: 5000
```

at the beginning of the database.yml and you'll be fine

Answer (score 2):

This is being caused by an invalid alias in your `database.yml` file. You most likely have something that looks close to this... but not quite:

```
defaults: &defaults
  adapter:  mysql2
  username: root
  password: 
  host:     localhost
  timeout:  5000

development:
  database: app_name_development
  <<: *defaults
```

In this, `&defaults` defines the alias that your error is talking about. Make your `database.yml` look more like this syntax and you should be set. Or, post your `database.yml` file here and we can help you fix it specifically if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The content of the database.yml file is:

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3_production
```

I am using netbeans as text editor and there is a error at the top of the file indicating:

*ComposerException null we had this found undefined alias default*

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You might need to upgrade your ruby > 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the password DB has some special character if you used rbenv-vars Plugin, change the password without special character.

Answer (score 0):

The pysch gem has a breaking change where it will not allow loading YAML files containing aliases by default.

Here's an example of a YAML:

```yaml
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
```

Since you don't control the code in question you can either modify your yml files (e.g. database.yml) to not use aliases or monkey patch the psych code.

There is a lot more detail in this answer, even though the error message has been updated.

[visit_Psych_Nodes_Alias: Unknown alias: default (Psych::BadAlias)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71191685/visit-psych-nodes-alias-unknown-alias-default-psychbadalias)