# Unknown alias when loading any yaml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, yaml

When I try to load any yaml file in my app, I get this error:

```
Psych::BadAlias: Unknown alias: default
  /Users/luizkowalski/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:385:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Alias'
  /Users/luizkowalski/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit'
  /Users/luizkowalski/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
  /Users/luizkowalski/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:31:in `accept'
  /Users/luizkowalski/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:321:in `block in revive_hash'
  /Users/luizkowalski/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:319:in `each'
  /Users/luizkowalski/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:319:in `each_slice'
  /Users/luizkowalski/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:319:in `revive_hash'
  /Users/luizkowalski/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:161:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
  /Users/luizkowalski/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit'
  /Users/luizkowalski/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
  /Users/luizkowalski/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:31:in `accept'
  /Users/luizkowalski/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:321:in `block in revive_hash'
  /Users/luizkowalski/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:319:in `each'
  /Users/luizkowalski/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:319:in `each_slice'
  /Users/luizkowalski/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:319:in `revive_hash'
  /Users/luizkowalski/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:161:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
  /Users/luizkowalski/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit'
  /Users/luizkowalski/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
  /Users/luizkowalski/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:31:in `accept'
  /Users/luizkowalski/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:295:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Document'
  /Users/luizkowalski/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit'
  /Users/luizkowalski/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
  /Users/luizkowalski/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:31:in `accept'
  /Users/luizkowalski/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:295:in `safe_load'
  /Users/luizkowalski/rails_dev/api/app/services/country_products_limitations_policy.rb:3:in `<class:CountryProductsLimitationsPolicy>'
```

I'm updating a Rails app from 4.1 to 4.2.8 using Ruby 2.2.3.

The yaml file is this one:

```
default: &default
  no_yearly_plans:
    - TH
    - SD
    - PK
    - SA
    - BH
    - SY
    - IQ
    - QA
    - YE
    - BY
    - OM
    - JO
    - CI
    - KW
    - AE

production:
  <<: *default

staging:
  <<: *default

development:
  <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default
```

My first assumption was that this file was wrong, but all linters says it is fine, so I don't know what could be

Comment: I've sucessfully parsed that file by using `irb` and `psych-2.2.4`. Which version of psych are you using? Are you sure that the error is related to that  yaml file?

Comment: I'm using 2.2.4 as well. Now I'm not sure anymore since it also happens to database.yml file

Comment: Could you show us your `database.yml`? (with truncated passwords and hosts).

Comment: I can, but again, it happen with ANY yaml file, and it wasn't happening since I updated Rails to 4.2.8

Comment: Could you please check if [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30114479/3255098) does something for you?

Comment: Nope, what actually work was use `YAML.load_file('config/file.yml')` instead `YAML.safe_load File.open(Rails...))`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you use `safe_load` you need to explicitly enable aliases:

```
YAML.safe_load path_to_yaml, [], [], true
```

Comment: `YAML.safe_load yaml, aliases: true` also does the trick
https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html#method-c-safe_load

Comment: ...for Ruby 2.6 or newer

Comment: Worth noting that `safe_load` will return you the file path in older versions, use `safe_load_file` instead. Or manually open the file and use `safe_load`